# How to access an variable set on the environment class in a worker instance in locust

Tags: python, locust

I have a custom fork of locust to which I am adding custom UI fields to the start and edit screens on locust. I have added the fields to the existing form in `index.html`. On `web.py`, in the /swarm method, I added the request results from the new UI fields to variables on the environment.

Now in my locust file I can access these variables from the environment in an event class like this:

```
@events.test_start.add_listener
def test_start(environment):
    print(environment.variable1)
    print(environment.host)
```

The problem with this is it only runs on the master instance of locust. I need the data inside of the on_start method of my HTTP user class. I think this is possible because inside of the HHTP user class I can get the `self.environment.host` and it will populate correctly but if I do `self.environment.variable1` it always comes back at `None`.

I added the new variable to the top of the env class in `env.py` and set the variables in `web.py` in the `/swarm` block with something like:

```
environment.variable1 = request.form["variable1"]
```

I think the problem is the WebUI class is only spawned on the master instance but this problem is still bypasses somehow with host. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, instead of maintaining your own fork of Locust, you could consider [adding your own web routes](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#adding-web-routes) and [extending the web UI to add the custom logic and data that you need](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#extending-web-ui). Could be better for you long-term from a maintenance perspective.

As far as getting that data to the workers, you could either create a web route that they could call, which you could do [on test start](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#test-start-and-test-stop), or you could [send a message](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html#communicating-across-nodes) from the master to the workers. Example from the Locust docs:

```
from locust import events
from locust.runners import MasterRunner, WorkerRunner

# Fired when the worker recieves a message of type 'test_users'
def setup_test_users(environment, msg, **kwargs):
    for user in msg.data:
        print(f"User {user['name']} recieved")
    environment.runner.send_message('acknowledge_users', f"Thanks for the {len(msg.data)} users!")

# Fired when the master recieves a message of type 'acknowledge_users'
def on_acknowledge(msg, **kwargs):
    print(msg.data)

@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
        environment.runner.register_message('test_users', setup_test_users)
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        environment.runner.register_message('acknowledge_users', on_acknowledge)

@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(environment, **_kwargs):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
        users = [
            {"name": "User1"},
            {"name": "User2"},
            {"name": "User3"},
        ]
        environment.runner.send_message('test_users', users)
```

Comment: I tried to go down the route of adding my own route to the locust but it does not allow you to add custom html to the start and edit screen. I'll try out tomorrow the message approach to get the new data to the worker nodes. Thanks!

Comment: It's still possible. At very least you can take your forked `index.html` and serve it at a different route and use that to start your load test instead (http://localhost:8089/new_index). At least then you're only maintaining the single forked file inside your repo. You could also consider creating a PR for Locust upstream to allow extending the first page.

Comment: Hmm good point on the just maintaining the one new file. I'll resort to that if I cannot get the messages thing to not work. I had a PR open before to add the changes to index.html to locust itself but the maintainers wanted to go a different direction on how to customize start params.

Comment: @ThomasWoeste I made a PR more in line with what I suggested. It could definitely be argued that custom arguments should be automatically propagated to workers as well (the PR doesnt do that yet) https://github.com/locustio/locust/pull/1841